# is there any tool for arangoDB

Tags: arangodb

Like there is Workbench for MySQL,
SQL Management studio for MS SQL,
Is there any tool for arangoDB?

I have searched a lot but found no solution.

Your help is much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: there is this arangoSH, but it is command line type.. i want GUI tool for arangoDB. is there any?

Comment: arangodb comes with a web interface - have you tried this?

Comment: no. where can i find this web interface?

Comment: if your ArangoDB server is running on localhost with default settings, then the web interface should be available at  
    http://localhost:8529/

Comment: thank you. i found the web interface. but is there no windows based tool for arangoDB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there is no desktop based management tool for ArangoDB on Windows, so you will have to stick either with [web interface](https://www.arangodb.org/manuals/current/UserManualWebInterface.html) or [shell](https://www.arangodb.org/manuals/current/UserManualArangosh.html). Web interface provides almost everything you need to manage your ArangoDB instance(s), but if you have any suggestions the best place would be to discuss it on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/arangodb).

Comment: First, the Arango Web Interface tool does most anything that Workbench for MySQL does, plus it does several additional things. Instead of being a "fat client application" like Workbench, the Web Interface displays and accepts commands through a web page via port 8529 of the Arango application on your computer, ie, it uses HTML in your browser, instead of Win32 in a Windows client. Said another way, it is a Windows based DB admin tool that's integrated with the database, and displays through your browser.